# Google Calendar API - create event PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to insert a new event into Google Calendar by using the Google Calendar API.
And the problem is that I want to set the event status to "free" or "busy" based on the input datetime data.

[image]

How to change the event status to "Free"? When I create a new event, it will automatically set to "Busy". I couldn't figure it out on how to set to "Free" or "Busy".

How I insert a new event by using Google Calendar API.

```
$googleClient = new GoogleClient();
$slotCalendarService = GoogleClientCalendar::getSlotCalendar($googleClient->getClient());

$googleEvent = new Event();

$googleEventStart = new EventDateTime();
$googleEventStart->setTimeZone($attrs['timezone']);
$googleEventStart->setDateTime("2021-12-02T10:00:00");
$googleEvent->setStart($googleEventStart);

$googleEventEnd = new EventDateTime();
$googleEventEnd->setTimeZone($attrs['timezone']);
$googleEventEnd->setDateTime("2021-12-02T10:50:00");
$googleEvent->setEnd($googleEventEnd);

$googleEventAttendee = new EventAttendee();
$googleEventAttendee->email = empty($attrs['attendee']) ? '' : $attrs['attendee'];
$googleEvent->description = $description;
$googleEvent->summary = $remark;
$googleEvent->setAttendees($googleEventAttendee);
$slotCalendarService->getCalendarService()->events->insert($slotCalendarService->getCurrentCalendarId(), $googleEvent);
```

Base on the the code above, there is no param to set the event status to "free" or "busy".
I also follow the document [FreeBusy Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query) and it does not have information on how to set event status to "free" or "busy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to set to "free", please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
$googleEvent->setAttendees($googleEventAttendee);
$slotCalendarService->getCalendarService()->events->insert($slotCalendarService->getCurrentCalendarId(), $googleEvent);
```

#### To:

```
$googleEvent->setAttendees($googleEventAttendee);
$googleEvent->transparency = "transparent"; // Added
$slotCalendarService->getCalendarService()->events->insert($slotCalendarService->getCurrentCalendarId(), $googleEvent);
```

- When you don't use `$googleEvent->transparency = "transparent";` or you use `$googleEvent->transparency = "opaque";`, it's "busy".

#### Reference:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)